# Having Trouble Mounting HFS Filesystem at Boot on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, boot, mount, fstab, hfs

While the command "sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdc1 /home/external3" mounts the hfs file system on the /home/external3 directory on my Ubuntu server, I don't understand how to get it to mount at boot.  In other words, if I reboot, I lose connection to the external hfs file system.

I should note that my other external file system (ext4) mounts just fine at boot.

I've tried different configurations in /etc/fstab, but to no satisfactory end.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert, but I would think adding the following to /etc/fstab should mount at boot:

/dev/sdc1 /home/external3 hfs defaults 0 0

That being said, I would probably find the UUID of your external hfs drive

sudo blkid

and use that instead, i.e.

UUID= /home/external3 hfs defaults 0 0

I also read somewhere that you might need to try hfsplus instead of hfs as the file system.

What is the line you've added to fstab? Including that might help.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestions, but so far, no dice.   In fstab, I have the following external drive config fo my ext4 file system: /dev/sdb1   /home/external2 ext4   defaults  0 0.                                                               When I attempt to automount my hfs file system, I use this in fstab: /dev/sdc1 /home/external3 hfsplus  defaults  0 0. I have also tried it with the UUID instead of /dev/sdb1 or sdc1, but still no joy.